# Index operation in TensorFlow

Tags: indexing, tensorflow

When I was doing batch labeling for some data, I have a variable for recording all calculation results:

```
p_all = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_num, batch_size]), name = "probability");
```

In the calculation, I have a loop to deal with each batch:

```
for i in range(batch_num):
    feed = {x: testDS.test.next_batch(batch_size)}
    sess.run(p_each_batch, feed_dict=feed)
```

How can I copy value of `p_each_bach` into `p_all` ?

To be more clear, I want something like:

```
... ...
p_all[batch_index,:] = p_each_batch
for i in range(batch_num):
    feed = {x: testDS.test.next_batch(batch_size), batch_index: i}
    sess.run(p_all, feed_dict=feed)
```

How can I make those code actually work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `p_all` is a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable), you can use the [`tf.scatter_update()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#scatter_update) op to update individual rows in each batch:

```
# Equivalent to `p_all[batch_index, :] = p_each_batch`
update_op = tf.scatter_update(p_all,
                              tf.expand_dims(batch_index, 0),
                              tf.expand_dims(p_each_batch, 0)) 

for i in range(batch_num):
    feed = {x: testDS.test.next_batch(batch_size), batch_index: i}
    sess.run(update_op, feed_dict=feed)
```